# grails apps - are .java files interpreted as groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

A bit confused about what Grails does with source code in a .java file.

If I have a class in a .java file in a grails project, and a method in the class has no modifier,  is that interpreted according to the groovy rules (treated as public) or the java rules (treated as package private)?

If I wanted to make sure the class was treated as package private would I have to change it to groovy and mark it @PackageScope, or can I use that modifier in .java files, or can I just leave it without a modifier and it will be scoped accofrding to Java rules as package-private.

What about other differences (like ==) -- in .java files -are they interpreted as groovy or as java?

Thanks.

Comment: The code either treated as Java *or* Groovy, not both. It should be clear from a method definition how the file is being handled.

Comment: .java interpreted as Java, .groovy interpreted as Groovy

Comment: Thanks -- just to be crystal clear, if I import a java class from a different package into a groovy class, the java class still works like a java class right?  That is, if there is no modifier on a method of the imported java class, that method is inaccessible correct?

Comment: with the default grails/groovy compiler settings and without annotating e.g. with `@CompileStatic` you can access protected/private/package level attributes and methods on a java class.  is it good practice?  no!